# Проблема при выключении Linux

Tags: linux, linux-mint

У меня стоит Linux Mint 18.2 При выключении у меня комп останавливается на строке

```
[OK] Stopped target Host and Network Name Lookups
```

Причем не каждый раз а через раз. Все сеансы всегда корректно закрываю. И python, и mysql.

Comment: Смотри в логи `journactl`

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, это не остановка, а ожидание. Т.е. было ранее TCP соединение (именно - TCP) с кем-то типа *Network Name Lookup*. Потом сервер "с той" стороны соедиенеие закрыл и отправил об этом сообщение на *host*. Но *host* этого сообщения не получил по какой-то причине. Вы командуете *halt* Вашему хосту и он пытается закрыть это соединение. Посылает запрос. Но ответа нет - "там" уже всё давно закрылось. *host* предпринимает повторные попытки. ЕМНИП, по умолчанию это продолжается 20 минут. После чего *host* благополучно ляжет.

Comment: так стопед[ok] - остановился уже